# Can we create a Oracle VM using vagrant inside a Azure VM?

Tags: oracle, azure, vagrant, virtual-machine

I tried to create a VM using vagrant inside an Azure VM.

1. **Vagrant Init** - This step was successful and I have updated the base to CentOS-7.5
2. **Vagrant Up** - When this command is executed, all the process went through and during the booting up step, My Azure VM is getting
   rebooted instead of the new VM which has been created using vagrant.

Is it possible to create a VM inside an Azure VM or Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

Azure VMs support Nested Virtualization that allows you to run a Hypervisor inside a Virtual Machine running on a Hypervisor.
You can review the VM sizes that support nested virtualization [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-the-new-dv3-and-ev3-vm-sizes/). 
Also, see the following articles/ docs to answer any additional questions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nested-virtualization

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization-azure-virtual-network

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization